# StackExchange.Redis SortAndStoreAsync

Tags: stackexchange.redis

I am trying to call the above to cache a sorted list of people on update

```
public Task WriteAsync(IDataTransaction transaction, Person model)
{
    var redis = transaction.GetContext<RedisTransactionContext>().RedisTransaction;

    redis.SetAddAsync("people", model.Identifier);
    redis.StringSetAsync(model.Identifier, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
    redis.StringSetAsync($"people_name_{model.Identifier}", model.Name.FullReverse());

    redis.SortAndStoreAsync("people_by_name", "people", by: "people_name_*");

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I then call

```
var database = _connection.GetDatabase();
var identifiers = await database.ListRangeAsync("people_by_name", index, index + count);
```

but it does not find the new list as SortAndStoreAsync has not created the sorted list - all the other data is there

am I doing something wrong, is SortAndStoreAsync supported inside a transaction?

Comment: Why don't you change it to public `async Task WriteAsync...` and then `await` `redis.SetAddAsync` etc?

Comment: Its all fire and forget. As far as I remember it used to timeout a lot if you awaited. Old code though, using async and await as you'd expect now-a-days.

Comment: Even now you're not meant to use `await` apparently: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/711#issuecomment-1767688918

Answer (score 0):

ah, I didn't add the SortType.Alphabetic

```
redis.SortAndStoreAsync("people_by_name", "people", by: "people_name_*", sortType: SortType.Alphabetic);
```

as you were SO :)